# Trying to figure out how to center my React card components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, card

[image: Code of my component] 
[image: screenshot of my rendered page]

I'm trying to center the cards so they appear with even space on both sides. I'm using the inhouse card component within React. I've tried using Flex but no such luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Would be better if you post the code here directly rather than an image of the code. Use the code icon to format the code correctly.

Comment: Also since this is most certainly CSS you need to show the CSS that you do have. What is the 'flex' class for instance? What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Grid

Below is the reference link
[Material design Grid layout](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)

Embed the Card Component between Grid